# Show index.html: how to make good config

Tags: nginx

**nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)**

```
server {
    listen       10.1.94.11:80;
    server_name  psywomenandmen.ru www.psywomenandmen.ru;

    location = /push/ {
        root   /home/h105667446/psywomenandmen.ru/docs/push;
        index index.html;
        http2_push main.css;
        add_header 'Debug' 'true';
    }
}
```

**Files**

```
h105667446@h105667446:~/psywomenandmen.ru/docs/push$ ls
index.html  main.css
```

When I open in the browser https://psywomenandmen.ru/push, I get 404 Error.
The error log is empty.

Could you help me show the index html?

Comment: Works for me (if your index.html is supposed to say "test")

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the root directive. It tells nginx to use the given path as the root (domain.com/) of the request. In your case nginx uses /home/.../docs/push as the root. When you enter domain.com/push, nginx searches for the index file in /home/.../docs/push/push.

root is usually used to define for the whole server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/.../docs;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

or if you /push/ to link to an entirely different path use alias:

```
server 80 {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        alias /home/.../docs/push;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```